# Recent Ubuntu update has killed my rutorrent/rtorrent link

Tags: nginx, rtorrent, rutorrent

I just installed the latest updates to Ubuntu 14.04.  Everything seems to be working properly.  rtorrent is working.  nginx is running php5-fpm is running and yet when I try to connect to rtorrent with rutorrent, rutorrent comes up but doesnt connect to rtorrent.

I did notice one thing - for some reason my ip address has changed.  It was 192.168.0.34 and now it's 192.168.0.36 but the connection is working fine and rtorrent is uploading and downloading fine.

I'm finding it hard to diagnose because all of the individual parts seem to be working but the whole is not.  Would really appreciate some help with trying to diagnose the problem and fixing it.

Here are the errors I get

```
[26.06.2014 00:13:59] Bad response from server: (502 [error,getplugins]) <html> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center> </body> </html>
[26.06.2014 00:13:59] Bad response from server: (502 [error,getuisettings]) <html> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.6.0</center> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I have discovered the following error in the nginx error log                 2014/06/26 08:30:58 [crit] 1733#0: *12 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /rutorrent/php/getsettings.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/rutorrent/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a huge problem for me at the same time that you posted your question as well. The issue appears to be permissions changes for `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

I fixed it by uncommenting these settings in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
listen.owner = www-data  
listen.group = www-data  
listen.mode = 0660
```

[According to this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231143) it appears that the default owner and group of the socket was changed to root instead of `www-data` by the latest security update. I'm decidedly disappointed that they pushed this change, which is a regression in terms of this issue.